# How to smooth the perimeter output of bwperim?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a segmented image
 [image: segmented result of original RGB image]

When I apply bwperim function on this I get the output as below

[image: perimeter got after applying bwperim]

I want to have a thin line of perimeter - just one pixel-thick. This is essential for further processing work. What is the best approach?

Please suggest.

======
BoundingBox

%%% ComputeBoundingBox
%%%
function [stats, statsAlreadyComputed] = ...
    ComputeBoundingBox(imageSize,stats,statsAlreadyComputed)
%   [minC minR width height]; minC and minR end in .5.

if ~statsAlreadyComputed.BoundingBox
    statsAlreadyComputed.BoundingBox = 1;

```
[stats, statsAlreadyComputed] = ...
    ComputePixelList(imageSize,stats,statsAlreadyComputed);

num_dims = numel(imageSize);

for k = 1:length(stats)
    list = stats(k).PixelList;
    if (isempty(list))
        stats(k).BoundingBox = [0.5*ones(1,num_dims) zeros(1,num_dims)];
    else
        min_corner = min(list,[],1) - 0.5;
        max_corner = max(list,[],1) + 0.5;
        stats(k).BoundingBox = [min_corner (max_corner - min_corner)];
    end
end
```

end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is happening because your image had quantization error when you were saving the image.  Did you save your image using a **lossy** compression algorithm, like JPEG?  If you want to preserve the intensities so that they don't change when you save the image, use a **lossless** compression algorithm, like PNG.

To eliminate these "noisy" effects, threshold your image first to eliminate any quantization errors so that you can set these pixels to completely white, then try using `bwperim` again.  In other words, do something like this:

```
im = im2bw(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/dagEc.png'));
im_noborder = imclearborder(im);
out = bwperim(im_noborder);
imshow(out);
```

The first line of code reads in your image directly from StackOverflow and we use [`im2bw`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2bw.html) to threshold your image.  This image was originally grayscale, and so we want to convert this into black and white only.  This will also remove any quantization artifacts as it thresholds anything higher than 128.  The next line of code removes the white border with [`imclearborder`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imclearborder.html) that surrounds your shape because the image you uploaded has a white border surrounding it for some reason.  Once we remove this border, we then apply `bwperim` and we show the image.

This is the image I get:

[image]

Comment: Ray, I have a question regd regionprops output. When I try to extract any property say eccentricity or centroid I get 255 values for the above contour. There is only one single boundary. Should it not be regarded as a single object and hence return only one value?

Comment: @parie - I don't think you did it properly.  I just read in the above image directly from StackOverflow and ran `regionprops`.  I only get one object.  This is the code that I ran: `im = imread('http://i.stack.imgur.com/wqA4y.png'); f = regionprops(im);`.  This is the output I got: `f = Area: 224, Centroid: [142.1339 70.8259], BoundingBox: [103.5000 35.5000 75 73]`.  Suggest you check your code again and check if you're reading the right image.  I believe you are using the **non-threhsolded** image, not the final result that's stored in `out` in my code.

Comment: Ray, I had uploaded jpg image. The first two images. I guess while uploading stackoverflow site converted them to .png image format. When I tried with output image uploaded by you I did get a single numeric answer.

Comment: Is there a way to get the png format output[with the boundary as above] from segmented result in jpg format?

Comment: Unfortunately no. JPG is a lossy compression algorithm. Btw I uploaded that image as PNG. Perhaps you can try setting the `Quality` flag to 100 when using `imwrite` and see if that helps. I can't guarantee no quantization error though.

Comment: Ray, I have to find the area of bounding box for the above image. I used regionprops. >> i=imread('wqA4y.png');
>> bb=regionprops(i,'BoundingBox')

bb = 

    BoundingBox: [103.5000 35.5000 75 73]

>> bb.BoundingBox(3)*bb.BoundingBox(4)

ans =

        5475. I am a bit confused in interpreting boundingbox values. The last two values are the distance in the direction of x and y axis right? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @parie yes. They are the width and height of the box respectively

Comment: I need to understand how the inbuilt function regionprops works when it computes Bounding Box values. I have pasted the code in the question space.  min_corner = min(list,[],1) - 0.5; and  max_corner = max(list,[],1) + 0.5; I am unable to get how corner co-ordinates are evaluated here. Please help.

Comment: @parie - Make a new question.  I consider your other question solved.